# How do I reverse spplot colour key so the values are decreasing?

Tags: r, sp

How do I reverse the colour key in a spplot so the that values are decreasing from the top to the bottom? Demo from https://edzer.github.io/sp/ below.

```
require(sp)
demo(meuse, ask = FALSE, echo = FALSE) 
spplot(meuse, "zinc", do.log = TRUE,
    key.space=list(x = 0.1, y = 0.95, corner = c(0, 1)),
    scales=list(draw = TRUE))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a factor column before plotting, then you have full control over the order.
E.g. for your example:

```
vals <- meuse$zinc
# compute breaks (equivalent to `do.log = TRUE`)
breaks <- c(min(vals),
            tail(head(exp(seq(min(log(vals)), max(log(vals)), length=6)), -1), -1),
            max(vals))
categories <- cut(vals, breaks, dig.lab=4, include.lowest=TRUE)

# add factor column to `SpatialPointsDataFrame`
meuse$zinc_cat <- forcats::fct_rev(categories)  # reverse order

spplot(meuse, "zinc_cat", key.space = list(x = 0.1, y = 0.95, corner = c(0, 1)))
```

[image: ssplot]